# Why can't an HTML anchor change the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I'm making a sliding effect which is similar to carousel. I set up four boxes, the contents of each box is different, and I use a nav to navigate.

I found every time I refresh, the page will return to the first box. But I hope the page returns to the box before refresh. Moreover, when I click on the 'a' tags, "#box*" will not be added to the URL. How can this be resolved?

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-list span2">
    <li class="nav-header">nav</li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#box1" class="link">box1</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#box2" class="link">box2</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#box3" class="link">box3</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#box4" class="link">box4</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<li id="box1" class="box">

    <div>XXXXX</div>
</li>

<li id="box2" class="box">

    <div>XXXXX</div>
</li>
```

#### JavaScript code

```
$('a.link').click(function(){
    $(this).parents("ul").children("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parents("li").addClass("active");
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the javascript code you use please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add id="box1", id="box2", ...
to the elements you want the browser to jump to.

For example:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-list span2">
    <li class="nav-header">nav</li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#box1" class="link">box1</a>
    </li>

    <a href="#box2" class="link">box2</a>

    <li>
        <a href="#box3" class="link">box3</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#box4" class="link">box4</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="box1">
    <h2>yo box1</h2>

    Put a lot of content here
</div>

<div id="box2">
    <h2>yo box2</h2>

    Put a lot of content here
</div>
```

That will add the hash to your URL with the id of the box, so when you refresh it will also work.

Comment: Thank you, I've done that, but still have no effect '<li id="box1" class="box"> <a name="box1">&nbsp;</a><div>XXXXX</div></li> '              @Eran H.

Comment: I didn't understand your html, your anchor tag still needs the href="#box1" attribute
and why the anchor that is pointing on box1 is inside box1? look again at my example

Comment: I change my code in my question ,but it still does not work..   @Eran H.

Comment: That's weird, you tried copying the html I wrote and it still doesn't work?
Put content where I wrote "Put here a lot of content" so you will see the browser scrolling to your the specific div.
If you don't have scrolling you won't notice the differnece.

Comment: Make your box1 larger, try adding a css with height:800px or add a lot of <br/> tags. Just so you will see how it works

Comment: I think you made it into invalid HTML (near "box2"). Have you?

Answer (score 0):

When you use an anchor, <a href="#box1">, there must be another another area on the page that has "#box1" ID to go to.  If you're not seeing any `#` in the address bar then your JavaScript is causing a problem.

Example: [jsfiddle.net/dc5vq/1](http://jsfiddle.net/dc5vq/1/)

#### Code:

```
<a href="#go1">go to 1</a><br><br>
<a href="#go2">go to 2</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1 id="go1">This is Go1</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1 id="go2">This is Go2</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: thanks a lot，I changed my code in my question as you say,but it still  does not work,can you help me?    @tonechild

Comment: What are all the `<br>`s for?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 return false;
```

from the script. This will add #box* to the URL.

Comment: Are you sure it will add `#box*`?